# sprintf returns 1-line char-array when using \n

Tags: matlab, printf, matlab-figure

I'm trying to relabel figures using this code:

```
h=findobj(gcf,'Type','Axes','Tag','colorbar');
oldlabels = str2num(get(h,'YTickLabel'));
newlabels = sprintf('%u%%\n',oldlabels*100)
```

At this point the Output in the commandwindow Looks like the desired `6x3-Char` but it isn't. Instead the `\n` is counted as a usual char and the result is a `24x1-Char`. So when I use

```
set(h,'YTickLabel',newlabels);
```

it obviously won't work. Is there anything I can replace the `\n` with so that `sprintf` will return the desired Array dimensions?

Here's an example for oldlabel:

```
oldlabels =

    0.1000
    0.2000
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.5000
    0.6000
```

EDIT:
@matlabgui I'm using R2010b and your solution gets me this:
[image: Doesn't really look correct]

Comment: Can you give an (exact MATLAB syntax) example of `oldlabels` so we can see the type and size? Does the `YTickeLabel` not expect a cell array? Also, are you using `\n` to try differentiate between different labels or are you trying to create multi-line labels?

Comment: I thought the input for YTickLabel had to be an Array of Strings, don't think newlabels should be made by `sprintf`.

Comment: @Dan I edited the example (not sure if this is what you wanted though). And no, if i create a char Array manually to the right dimensions, the `set`-command works. Also if you use `get('axeshandle') you'll see, that the property 'YTickLabel' is a char Array.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Why not? Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @Max how about leaving off the `\n` and using `reshape` on `newlabels` instead?

Comment: @Dan Yes, that should work! I'll try and let you know in a few mins :)

Comment: @Dan ok `reshape(newlabels,[],3)` actually does the Job, but the figure still doesn't look right. But your answer works if you Change str2double to str2num, so I'm fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to `sprintf` is to just iterate over the array:

```
axes
h = colorbar;
oldlabels = str2double(get(h,'YTickLabel')); %// or str2num
newlabels = arrayfun(@(x)[num2str(x),'%'],oldlabels*100,'uni',0);
set(h,'YTickLabel', newlabels);
```

Comment: Your answer makes a legend consisting of `NaN%`'s, but if you Change str2double to str2num, it works just fine. I'll accept if you correct ;)

Comment: @Max I don't have an old version of MATLAB to test this on, but `str2double` seems to work on my test case in 2015a. I've added `str2num` as an alternative in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (r2015a):

```
axes
h = colorbar;
oldlabels = str2double(get(h,'YTickLabel'));
newlabels = sprintf('%u%%\n',oldlabels*100);
set(h,'YTickLabel', newlabels);
```

[image]